# php, how to compare the 2 arrays from different queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pattern-matching

i have 2 queries, and i get back some data by doing a `whyle` loop.

from the first query if i do `print_r($final_key);`i get:

```
hey1
hey2
hey3
```

from the second one, if i do `print_r($final_key2);` i get:

```
hey1 test
hey2 test1
hey3
```

what i am trying to do is to compare the 2 arrays and check for words that match 
and i can't do it directly from the database

any ideas?

thanks

edit:
here is my query 1:

```
while ($keywords = mysql_fetch_array($keys1, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    foreach ($keywords as $key) {
        $plus = '+';
        $pos = strripos($key, $plus);
            if ($pos === false) { } else { 
                $clean_plus = preg_replace("/[\+]/", '', $key);
                $final_key = str_replace("&#39;", "", $clean_plus);
                print_r($final_key);
                echo '<br>';
            }


    }
}
```

and the second one:

```
 <?php
 while ($keywords = mysql_fetch_array($keys)){
if($keywords['kword'] != ''){
    echo $keywords['kword'];
 } } ?>
```

i am tryingt o match `$final_key` against `$keywords['kword'];`

Comment: Could you give us a sample of the two arrays?  ie: `array("one"=>1, "two", "three")`

Comment: So you want a function that returns 'hey3' because that's the only word that is exactly the same in both arrays?

Comment: You *really* can't just do a DB join?

Comment: please see my edits. the join is out of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) which returns an array containing values in both arrays.

If you want the keys to match, use [array_intersect_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php).

Comment: i get arning: array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: You need to be more clear about what your variable types are. You start the question by saying you have two arrays. By the end of your edits, it looks like you're comparing two strings. Which is it?

Comment: sorry, i guess they are strings

Comment: If they're both strings, then why not standard compare `==`? If one is an array and the other is a string, you could use `array_search`. If you're looking to compare substrings in two strings separated by spaces (or another delimiter), you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get each substring as an array element. Then use `array_intersect`. If this is what you're trying to do, you should edit your question because it definitely doesn't look like that right now.

Answer (score 5):

Use `array_intersect`:

```
array_intersect($array1, $array2, ...);
```

from the [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) documentation:

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

Comment: i get arning: array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: `array_intersect` works on arrays; if you are trying to see if a string exists in an array, perhaps `array_search` would be a better function to use, but your question is unclear on what  you're comparing if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over one array, and on each iteration, loop the other.

```
<?php
foreach($array as $item){
    foreach($array2 as $item2){
        if($item == $item2){
            $array3[] = $item;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This will create an array of matches, which you can then do with as you will.

Comment: Looks like root45 has the solution... Oops.